# How to fix losing precision when encoding polylines for Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've found this well-referenced page [Encoding polylines for Google Maps](http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/GoogleMaps/EncodePolyline/). I've implemented their algorithms for encoding and decoding polylines in my application, but I'm facing some issues keeping the precision of the coordinates.

I've these coordinates for my polyline:

```
57.012415241636155, 9.99178024863532
57.012422477487256, 9.991334773101812
57.01190974033057, 9.99068645350514
```

If I encode them using [their encoder](http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/GoogleMaps/EncodePolyline/encodeForm.html) I get this encoded polyline:

```
qf~zIso~{@AxAfB`C
```

If I afterwards try to decode this encoded string using [their decoder](http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/GoogleMaps/EncodePolyline/decode.html) I get these coordinates:

```
57.01241, 9.99178
57.012420000000006, 9.991330000000001
57.011900000000004, 9.990680000000001
```

Why am I losing the precision of my coordinates? I need my encoded polyline to be more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are losing precision because encoding does that.

However, you most certainly do not need that precision. The distance between (57.012410, 9.991780) and (57.012411, 9.991781) — 1 at the sixth decimal place — is 12cm. Each digit at the fifth decimal place will be about a metre. The maps aren't that accurate.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Should I use five or six decimals for my coordinates?

Comment: Either. Five is standard if you're going to encode them, and the map isn't accurate enough to show a difference of a metre, anyway. There's absolutely no point in using more than six.