# Loss of precision after encoding polyline

Tags: c#, google-maps

After the encoding of a polyline, I lose the precision. The polyline doesn't fit the map.

How I can resolve the loss of precision?

This is the 10 first coords of the original polyline

[image]

[Encoded Polyline (download)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67997286/encoded%20polyline.txt)

To test the output I use this link:

[PolyLineUtility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility)

To encode the polyline I use this C# algorithm

```
 public static string Encode(IEnumerable<Coordinate> points)
 {
    var str = new StringBuilder();

    var encodeDiff = (Action<int>)(diff =>
    {
        int shifted = diff << 1;
        if (diff < 0)
            shifted = ~shifted;

        int rem = shifted;

        while (rem >= 0x20)
        {
            str.Append((char)((0x20 | (rem & 0x1f)) + 63));

            rem >>= 5;
        }

        str.Append((char)(rem + 63));
    });

    int lastLat = 0;
    int lastLng = 0;

    foreach (var point in points)
    {
        int lat = (int)Math.Round(point.Latitude * 1E5);
        int lng = (int)Math.Round(point.Longitude * 1E5);

        encodeDiff(lat - lastLat);
        encodeDiff(lng - lastLng);

        lastLat = lat;
        lastLng = lng;
    }

    return str.ToString();
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How I can resolve the loss of precision? I use a common algorithm for the encoding.

Comment: What is the datatype of point.Latitude  & point.Longitude?

Comment: I use float in the mssql db and in the linq2sql class it's a double. linq change the datatype in the .dbml.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix losing precision when encoding polylines for Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207351/how-to-fix-losing-precision-when-encoding-polylines-for-google-maps)