# iOS - Build polyline from Google Maps Directions API response

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-polyline

How can I get a `polyline` out of the Directions API JSON response?

Using the `overview_polyline` is not an option as it is only a smoothened version of the actual `polyline`.

I also tried getting the start and end location coordinates from the steps, however those will only give me a very inaccurate `polyline`, because they only contain a few coordiantes.

How can I get an accurate `polyline` out of the Directions response?

**EDIT**: Using @SaxonDruce answer, I can get accurate polylines however, they look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the sample response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#sample-response), you'll need something equivalent to:

```
response.routes[0].legs[0].steps[i].polyline.points
```

So, get the first route, then the first leg, then loop over the steps, then get the polyline, then get the points.

Comment: But this will give me the encoded polylines individually for every step, thus they would need to be drawn using multiple GMSPaths for each and every step. How can I combine them into one single GMSPath?  Also, the lines are very jiggery and have sharp edges using this method!

Comment: Your method works pretty well however, the only problem is that (due to drawing every polyline for the steps individually) the lines look very segmented and uneven (see edited answer).

Comment: @BalázsVincze for the first issue, I found http://stackoverflow.com/a/24096653/148241 which has some code for combining multiple `GMSPath` objects into a single `GMSMutablePath`.

Comment: For the second issue, it looks like the encoded polyline rounds the coordinates to approx the nearest metre. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207351/how-to-fix-losing-precision-when-encoding-polylines-for-google-maps and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394224/google-directions-api-encoded-polyline. I'm not sure if there's anything you can do about this to get a more accurate response from the Google API. Maybe you could filter out points which are close together? You'll still get segments, but they'll be longer and so maybe look better.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [saxon druce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148241/saxon-druce)'s answer, You can loop over all the steps of first leg and combine all the points to form a polyline.

```
List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
for (DirectionsStep step : legs[i].steps) {
    points.addAll(step.polyline.decodePath());
}
EncodedPolyline legPolyline = new EncodedPolyline(points);
```